# Interfaces and overloading a struct?

Tags: go, interface

I am completely new to go and am planning on building a bittorent client as my first project to learn the language. One aspect is econding and decoding of bittorrent files. An example that I've found creates a struct containing a bufio.Reader, and then uses some interfaces to add additional methods. Can someone explain the mechanism for constructing these interfaces in such a way that overloads the struct? I'm not clear on how the functions in this file are being added to the decoder struct (https://github.com/marksamman/bencode/blob/master/decoder.go):

```
package bencode

import (
    "bufio"
    "errors"
    "io"
    "strconv"
)

type decoder struct {
    bufio.Reader
}

func (decoder *decoder) readDictionary() (map[string]interface{}, error) {
    dict := make(map[string]interface{})
}

func (decoder *decoder) readString() (string, error) {
    ...
}

func (decoder *decoder) readList() ([]interface{}, error) {
    ...
}

func Decode(reader io.Reader) (map[string]interface{}, error) {
    decoder := decoder{*bufio.NewReader(reader)}
    if firstByte, err := decoder.ReadByte(); err != nil {
        return make(map[string]interface{}), nil
    } else if firstByte != 'd' {
        return nil, errors.New("bencode data must begin with a dictionary")
    }
    return decoder.readDictionary()
}
```

Comment: By "overload a struct", do you mean to call same method on a struct value with different type parameters? Because method overloading in that sense does not exist in go. https://golang.org/doc/faq#overloading

Comment: I guess overload is the incorrect term. I just don't understand how it's possible to call decoder.readList...it's simply a method, how is it being tied to the decoder struct?

Comment: Because readList is declared as a method. A method in go is similar to a class's instance method. The object on which the method acts (`this` or `self` in other languages) is coupled with that method using a "receiver". In `func (d *decoder) readList() ([]interface{}, error)` , `(d *decoder)` (d is a value having type `decoder` defined above) part is the object on which `readList` will operate on.

Comment: Maybe go is different than Java or JavaScript in this regard but I still don't see how decoder.readLine or decoder.readDictionary work in this context. In this file there is a struct that gets created in Decode()...how are thise methods associated with that struct (the decoder object)? Is this go file implicitly a class and the functions defined within it lonked to the decoder object?

Comment: Ahhh I've got it now. You mentioned "receivers". I found this and it all makes sense now: https://tour.golang.org/methods/3. Thanks!